# Factorization problem

Tags: encryption, public-key, cryptanalysis, discrete-logarithm, factoring

Say, $X= a\cdot b$, where $(a, b) \in Z_q^*$ and $q$ is a large prime. If $X$ is given, then what is the complexity (or hardness) of finding $a$ and $b$?

Note that, either $a$ or $b$ can be reused to compute another $X'$ which is also public.

Edited: (more details)

Let's say Alice chooses two random numbers $a, b\in Z^∗_q$ and computes $X=a\cdot b$. Alice publishes $X$. What is the complexity of Bob to guess (or compute) $a$ and $b$ from the known $X$ and $Z^∗_q$?

Comment: If the multiplication $X=a\cdot b$ is in $\Bbb N$, you are asking the complexity of integer factorization. For an heuristic and conjectured answer as useful in cryptography, see [GNFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve).

Answer (score 2):

> Say, $X= a\cdot b$, where $(a, b) \in Z_q^*$ and $q$ is a large prime. If $X$ is given, then what is the complexity (or hardness) of finding $a$ and $b$?

If the multiplication is done within $Z_q^*$, then it's easy - pick an arbitrary nonzero $a$ and compute $b = a^{-1}X$; you're done.  You can compute $a^{-1}$ by either the Extended Euclidean method, or by using $a^{-1} = a^{p-2}$

This will find a $(a, b)$ pair that satisfies the equation.  If you're looking for the unique one that someone else had in mind, well, you're out of luck - there are $q-1$ pairs that satisfy the equation, and with no other information, there is no way to determine which is the correct one.

Comment: thanks @poncho for your answer. I wanted to know the hardness of computing $a$ and $b$ ($a$ and $b$ are unique numbers chosen by a user) from $X$. Let's say Alice chooses two random numbers $a, b\in Z_q^*$ and computes $X= a\cdot b$. Alice publishes $X$. What is the complexity of Bob to guess (or compute) $a$ and $b$ from the known value $X$ and $Z_q^*$?

Comment: @Naz: Poncho's answer assumes that $X=a\cdot b$ is computed in $\Bbb Z^*_q$, that is modulo $q$, because your question suggests so. In that case, as explained in the last sentence of the answer, any guess of Bob with $a\cdot b\bmod q=X$, including $(a,b)=(1,X)$ or $(a,b)=(X,1)$, is as bad as any other, with low probability $1/(q-1)$ to be right, and complexity that of copying $X$, that is $\mathcal O(\log(X))$. Even if Bob chooses $a$ at random, complexity is the similarly low $\mathcal O((\log\log(q))^2\log(q))$.